# Google map highlight KML layers on mouse click

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I created a map using gmap3 jquery plugin and it is showing fine.

But I need to highlight the regions when we move the mouse on them.

I created the layers using Google Earth and it is saved in KML file. When I call the kml file it shows all the selected regions described in kml file.

1- I need to highlight only the region on which mouse clicked.
2- Get the value/id/address of the highlighted area.

I tried one code:

```
$("#my_map").height(300).gmap3({marker:{
latLng: [25.185442, 55.280040],
options:{
  draggable:true
},
events:{
  dragend: function(marker){
    $(this).gmap3({
      getaddress:{
        latLng:marker.getPosition(),
        callback:function(results){
          var map = $(this).gmap3("get"),
            infowindow = $(this).gmap3({get:"infowindow"}),
            content = results && results[1] ? results && results[1].formatted_address : "no address";
          if (infowindow){
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            infowindow.setContent(content);
          } else {
            $(this).gmap3({
      kmllayer:{
options:{
  url: "http://path_to_site/Dubai_Highlights.kml",
  opts:{
    suppressInfoWindows: true
  }
},
events:{
  click: function(kml, event){
    alert(content);
  }
}
}});
          }
}
      }
    });
  }
}
},
map:{
options:{
  zoom: 8
}
}

});
```

There is one website dubizzle.com and they are di when "Adding any ad" (Registration is required). So I am attaching the screenshot. http://i61.tinypic.com/3179p3b.png

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the featureData object. You can find the documentation on KML overlay [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#KmlMouseEvent). Also, this [link](http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/11-layers/kmllayer-45) will help embed it in your code.

If you want to set up your KML file there is link to a tool in the second link above. Hoepfully it is helpful.